# How to change the position of divs in asp.net form dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the design of web form I have four divs

- divGeneralDetails
- divLanguageDetails
- divLinkDetails
- divOperationalDetails

Divs mentioned above are displayed vertically in the form.

My question is.
Depending on value in query string, i will have to change the order in which divs are displayed.

In my `Page_Load` event

```
string FirstDiv = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

if value of FirstDiv is equal to "General"

```
 then order should be
   - divGeneralDetails    
   - divLanguageDetails    
   - divLinkDetails   
   - divOperationalDetails
```

if value of `FirstDiv` is equal to "Operational"

```
  then order should be
 - divOperationalDetails
 - divGeneralDetails    
 - divLanguageDetails    
 - divLinkDetails
```

How do I set this in `Page_Load` event. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can dynamically generate the divs.

Comment: how are you creating the divs right now? just change their order based on the value of `FirstDiv`

Comment: What does your markup look like?  Are the divs being created programmatically or declaratively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Panel.

Example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelMain" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="divGeneralDetails" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="divLanguageDetails" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="divLinkDetails" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="divOperationalDetails" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

And then rearrange it add code behind:

```
panelMain.Controls.Clear();
panelMain.Controls.Add(divOperationalDetails);
panelMain.Controls.Add(divGeneralDetails);
panelMain.Controls.Add(divLanguageDetails);
panelMain.Controls.Add(divLinkDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it server-side, then for good working of ViewState (if it is being used) the Divs would have to be added in the desired order using `Page.Controls.Add()` in the **`PreInit`** event of the Page. Any later may throw off ViewState.

A totally different approach would be to use jQuery in the browser to manipulate the Divs, see the snippet below for one way to achieve this:

```js
function moveOperationalToTop() {
  var specialId = "divOperationalDetails";
  var $main = $("#divMain");
  var $divs = $main.find('div');
  $main.empty();
  $divs.each(function() {
    if (this.id == specialId) $main.append($(this));
  });
  $divs.each(function() {
    if (this.id != specialId) $main.append($(this));
  });
}
```

```css
#divOperationalDetails {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divMain">
  <div id="divGeneralDetails">divGeneralDetails</div>
  <div id="divLanguageDetails">divLanguageDetails</div>
  <div id="divLinkDetails">divLinkDetails</div>
  <div id="divOperationalDetails">divOperationalDetails</div>
</div>
<button onclick="moveOperationalToTop()">Move Operational to top</button>
```